# Using Prettier to enforce Vue Style Guide

Tags: vue.js, eslint, vue-cli, prettier

I'm trying to implement the [Vue Style Guide](https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide) for my company's repo. I installed the linter using vue-cli and was asked which formatter I should use so I selected Prettier and I wanted it formatted on save and on commit.

I am getting the linting errors I'm expecting, however, Prettier isn't formatting anything. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Formatting must be explicitly run with the `lint` NPM script. It performs linting and auto-fixes (formatting) in the same command:

```
npm run lint
```